# Run two web application as Parent and Child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms, iis-7.5

We have a one big web application that has been around for some years and been written in asp.net web forms. recently we decided to rewrite some port of it with asp.net mvc.

Now they both depend on each other but have a common database. with the new changes, it requires the mvc application to be as a sub folder in the main web application. for example if the main domain which is the web forms is `www.mysite.com`, the path for mvc application must be `www.mysite.com/new`.

In iis 7.5, i created a new web site and inside it i put the main application and then i have added a new virtual directory to it and put the new mvc application.

Main application works fine but the mvc application does not work. it's seems there is some problem in web.config in main application.

Here is the web.config for web forms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="RegCompany.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="botDetect" requirePermission="false" type="BotDetect.Configuration.BotDetectConfigurationSection, BotDetect" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="RegCompany.DAL.MyRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="LoginName" defaultUrl="/Model/Login.aspx" loginUrl="/new" timeout="1440" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="BotDetect.Web.CustomSessionIdManager, BotDetect" />
    <pages enableSessionState="true">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="BotDetect" namespace="BotDetect.Web.UI" tagPrefix="BotDetect" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <applicationSettings>
    <RegCompany.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="RegCompany_linepayamak_Send" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://test.net/Post/Send.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </RegCompany.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyRegisterationContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CompanyRegisteration;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" />
      <add name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <botDetect helpLinkEnabled="true" helpLinkMode="image" />
</configuration>
```

And this for mvc application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="RegisterCompany.Web.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="true" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="botDetect" requirePermission="false" type="BotDetect.Configuration.BotDetectConfigurationSection, BotDetect" />
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
  </elmah>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyRegisterationContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CompanyRegisteration;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" />
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="BotDetect.Web.CustomSessionIdManager, BotDetect" />
    <pages enableSessionState="true">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="BotDetect" namespace="BotDetect.Web.UI" tagPrefix="BotDetect" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      <remove name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" />
      <add name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" />
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <RegisterCompany.Web.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="RegisterCompany_Web_test_linepayamak_Send" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://test.net/Post/Send.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </RegisterCompany.Web.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <elmah>
  </elmah>
  <botDetect helpLinkEnabled="true" helpLinkMode="image" />
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <!-- 
          For more information on how to configure Glimpse, please visit http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration
          or access {your site}/Glimpse.axd for even more details and a Configuration Tool to support you. 
      -->
  </glimpse>
</configuration>
```

What do i have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Be more concrete, define "mvc application does not work", it raises a .net exception? it raises an IIS configuration error? your server explodes?

Comment: [http://s32.postimg.org/hisk4lp7p/screencapture_localhost_90_new_1462280040312.png](See this image )

Comment: You're missing "BotDetect.dll", add it to the bin folder.

Comment: The problem solved by copying some dll to bin folder. Thanks.